# Flooring for Pool Shed

Tags: flooring, outdoor

I have scoured the internet for answers to this but can not find one. However I think I can ask a more intelligent question now that I have more information.

I have a pool shed (refrigerator, bench and changing area) maybe more than a shed but certainly not a house. There is electric but no climate control. I am in the North East where temperature can fall to 10 Degrees and rise to 95 degrees in a typical year. The shed is approximately 10 X 14 that is divided into two rooms. (4 x 10 and 10 x 10)

The subfloor seems like cement but I am not 100% sure. I want to paint and put flooring down. The old flooring was these tiles that were paper thin (vinyl?) that all buckled. Flooring is my question:

I would be happy with anything, carpet, rubber, vinyl plank or anything that is easy to install up to $2 a square foot. I looked at those vinyl planks but apparently they will have major contraction during winter (when it is unused) and can buckle, not to mention that all the instructions say not for outdoor non-climate spaces. I am not worried about the warranty just wether it will hold for five years at least. [https://www.homedepot.com/p/LifeProof-Sterling-Oak-8-7-in-x-47-6-in-Luxury-Vinyl-Plank-Flooring-20-06-sq-ft-case-I966106L/300699284?cm_sp=BazVoice-_-QA_PQRDR-*-300699284-*-x](https://www.homedepot.com/p/LifeProof-Sterling-Oak-8-7-in-x-47-6-in-Luxury-Vinyl-Plank-Flooring-20-06-sq-ft-case-I966106L/300699284?cm_sp=BazVoice-_-QA_PQRDR-_-300699284-_-x)

The floors people use for garages and or gyms that are rubber, I get the feeling they are not made to be trimmed. And with the wall dividing into two rooms I need a tighter fit than giant 12 x 12 tiles I can not trim.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/BlockTile-12-in-x-12-in-Modular-Interlocking-Garage-Floor-Tiles-Set-of-30-B0US4630/301985773

I heard people recommend sheet vinyl but that does not seem like it would hold up and I was thinking about outdoor carpet. 
***Anyone have any suggestions?*** I looked at questions about garages, cabins, sun-rooms and nothing seems to fit.

Comment: If $2.00 a square was not your limiting factor i would suggest a cedar slat floor, in sections that can be taken up for cleaning the cement. ( i have not done the math to know what the cost per square would be )

Comment: typical cedar fence planks cost _about_ $1/sqft; (0.5 X 6) / $3 per plank. I would consider a garage floor "paint" made of epoxy.

Comment: I was looking at those but they generally come in big 12/12 tiles. I will do some real measuring to see how it would work out. Keep in mind the there is a wall dividing the shed into two rooms with a doorway in the center so bif 12 x 12 can hard to manage if they cant be trimmed for a snug fit.

Comment: Fence planks would not be an interlocking system loops/tongues/grooves. I would have to saw planks and use some adhesive to hold it down. I am looking for the easier DIY where I can basically use a utility knife to cut planks., if possible

Comment: I would not use carpet in a pool area, I have seen it done but I have also seen rot caused by the moisture the carpet holds. I love epoxy paint but would add a special “sand” or non slip additive to the paint. I am not sure why you cannot trim the tiles this is a basic part of any tile job, tile will last as will epoxy paint but in a pool area I would use smaller tiles or a rough stone type surface so wet or damp floors are not a slip and fall hazard.